# When using the TlHelp32 library, how can I print a list of running processes to console?

Tags: c++, windows

Imagine this function:

```
void OutputAllRunningProcessNames()
{
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);
    Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry);
    do
    {
        std::cout << *(const char*)procEntry.szExeFile << std::endl;
    } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
    return;
}
```

I would expect this to give me a list of all process names however I only get the first letter of each one. I am printing procEntry.szExeFile, casted to a const char* and dereferenced, how do I tell the machine to keep reading the address szExeFile points to until it reaches a null terminator? Thanks.

Edit: It was only printing the first letters because I was dereferencing the const char* instead of passing it to cout and also there was a problem with my header file that was making it give me unicode when i specified ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop dereferencing the pointer and pass the pointer to `std::cout`.

```
std::cout << (const char*)procEntry.szExeFile << std::endl;
```

Comment: same result exactly nice try tho

Comment: Then it looks like there is a byte with value zero after the first letter. You should use ANSI version of the API (functions and structures with `A` suffix) to work with `const char*`.

Comment: Get rid of the type cast, it doesn't belong: `std::cout << procEntry.szExeFile << std::endl;`. If you see a memory address printed instead of string characters, it means you are using the `W` (Unicode) version of the API, so use `std::wcout` instead: `std::wcout << procEntry.szExeFile << std::endl;`